# Problem with starting foreman for Clojure app

Tags: ruby, clojure, heroku

I'm tried to follow the guide on getting a Clojure app on Heroku. Everything works fine except running it locally. I'm using Windows 7.

The step says:

1. gem install foreman
2. foreman start

On 1 I had to be admin, but the installation went ok

When I execute 2 I get:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- pty (LoadError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.19.0/lib/foreman/engine.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.19.0/lib/foreman/cli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.19.0/bin/foreman:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/bin/foreman:19:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/bin/foreman:19:in `<main>'
```

What am I missing?

When I run gem environment I get:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/henrik/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing my first answer, as it was entirely off-the-mark.

Looks like `pty` is part of standard Ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/index.html

However, based on a cursory glance of [this old forum post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/72810), it looks like Ruby's `pty` requires some things which are less-than-straightforward to implement on Windows, so it's very possible it's not available on Windows at this point either.

Comment: I get "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pty' (>= 0) in any repository".

Should it be available for Windows?

Comment: Yes. I found this issue explaining it: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/41