# Starting Foreman app in Ruby for Heroku installl

Tags: ruby, heroku, pty, foreman

I'm trying to deploy a simple app, getting started on Heroku/Cedar but it's imposible in Windows. Getting next error running 'foreman start', and also an error doing 'bundle install' and I'm stuck with it. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913529/problem-with-starting-foreman-for-clojure-app) they conclude it's imposible to work with it in windows, but I know people are working in Windows with the current version, so I don't know how they do it, if they use another gem instead of 'foreman'. I'm really new into this, so I can't manage a solution/workaround.

```
c:\workspace\rorprueba>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

c:\workspace\rorprueba>gem list | grep heroku
heroku (2.18.1)

c:\workspace\rorprueba>foreman start
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- pty (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.32.0/lib/foreman/engine.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.32.0/lib/foreman/cli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo m_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/foreman-0.32.0/bin/foreman:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/foreman:19:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/foreman:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't have true pseudoterminals, so the PTY library isn't available. Foreman requires this, and thus cannot work on Windows, it seems.

There seems to be someone working on a C# re-implementation of Foreman, you could have a look at it [here](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman-windows).

Source: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/41

You could also have a look in the file Procfile. This is what foreman uses to see what processes to start up. You could execute that command yourself instead of using foreman.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following [foreman for windows](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/159) might do the trick

```
$ gem install foreman --pre
```

Comment: thanks, I hope it helps somebody, but nowadays I don't need anymore  Heroku on Windows, thus I can't say if it relaly does the trick :-)